# SQLAlchemy: How to properly escape text for .update()

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

In using JSONB columns in a postgres + SQLAlchemy setup we often use the `.update()` method.

An example is:

```
path = '{user,lastText}'
text = 'Hello. Please activate folder \nD:\\foo\bar\some\more \t Thanks, yours "Ted"'

db.session.query(
  Customer
).filter(
  Customer.custid == '10'
).update(
  {Customer.context: func.jsonb_set(Customer.context, path, text)}, 
  synchronize_session='fetch'
)
```

You see that the text has plenty of problematic chars and needs to be escaped.

What's the recommended way to do that?
SQLAlchemy should have such a module?

Comment: Use `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I transformed your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ilja's answer is spot on:

```
json.dumps()
```

Its a very good way to go.